# How can I apply overflow: unset; after a CSS transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions

```
  #slide-buttons.horizontal {
      max-width: 0;
      transition:max-width 0.9s ease-out;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  #slide-buttons.horizontal.slide-in {
      max-width: 1000px;
      /*overflow: unset;*/
  }
```

I am trying to use the above style to make a slide-in menu. I want to start with a max-width of zero with overflow hidden and transition to a max-width of 1000px and overflow unset to simulate a menu "sliding-in" (or expanding from nothing whatever). The problem I am running into is the overflow property is not a transitional property, so I can't use a transition delay between the two overflow values I want to use. Does anyone know how I can apply the overflow:unset property *after* my max-width transition has finished?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CSS animation which changes `overflow` from `hidden` to `initial` and is delayed by duration of the transition.

```css
.max-width-container.slide-in {
  max-width: 1000px;
  animation-duration: 0;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-name: revert-overflow;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes revert-overflow {
  from {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  to {
    overflow: initial;
  }
}
```

Working example of this approach (with jQuery to demonstrate final effect):

```js
$(".toggle-container-button").click(function() {
  $(".max-width-container").toggleClass("slide-in");
})
```

```css
.max-width-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 0;
  height: 100px;
  transition: max-width 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.max-width-container.slide-in {
  max-width: 500px;
  animation-duration: 0;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-name: revert-overflow;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.overflowing-element {
  width: 550px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

@keyframes revert-overflow {
  from {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  to {
    overflow: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<button class="toggle-container-button">
  Toggle
</button>

<div class="max-width-container">
  <div class="overflowing-element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given how you've structured your classes, you are presumably using JS to make the menu work. In which case, you'd add the class controlling overflow from your JS after starting the menu animation, delaying by the time the animation takes (using `setTimeout()`).

Also, note that `unset` isn't a valid value for `overflow`. You probably want `initial` or perhaps explicitly to set `auto` or something like that.

Comment: Yeah I realized that was an option as well but I was hoping there was a pure CSS solution.

Comment: I don't think so. As you say, `overflow` can't be a transition property (given that overflow is either on or off, rather than a mix of the two, that makes sense!) and so you can't add a `transition-delay` to it. Annoying but ‍♂